# Stop jquery setInterval when get() == 'finished'?

Tags: javascript, jquery, get, setinterval

Does anyone know if there is any way to stop setInterval if scan_status.php == 'finished'?

Every 3 seconds data (html) is brought from scan_status.php.

What I want is to stop updating the data if the scan_status.php is finished.

Thanks in advance!

Ryan

```
 jQuery(function($){
setInterval(function(){
 $.get( 'dynamic/page_count.php?u=<?php echo $uid; ?>', function(newRowCount){
  $('#pagecounter').html( newRowCount );
 });
 $.get( 'dynamic/individual_count.php?u=<?php echo $uid; ?>', function(newIndRowCount){
  $('#individual_counter').html( newIndRowCount );
 });
 $.get( 'dynamic/total_word_count.php?u=<?php echo $uid; ?>', function(totalWordCount){
  $('#total_word_count').html( totalWordCount );
 });
 $.get( 'dynamic/scan_status.php?u=<?php echo $uid; ?>', function(scanStatus){
  $('#scan_status').html( scanStatus );
 });
 $.get( 'dynamic/download_status.php?u=<?php echo $uid; ?>', function(downloadStatus){
  $('#download_status').html( downloadStatus );
 });
},3000); // 5000ms == 5 seconds
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save a reference to the `setInterval` handler by storing the returned value from the call.

```
var interval = setInterval(function(){...});
```

and when you want to clear it use `clearInterval( interval );`

So in your example

```
jQuery(function($){
var interval = setInterval(function(){
 $.get( 'dynamic/page_count.php?u=<?php echo $uid; ?>', function(newRowCount){
  $('#pagecounter').html( newRowCount );
 });
 $.get( 'dynamic/individual_count.php?u=<?php echo $uid; ?>', function(newIndRowCount){
  $('#individual_counter').html( newIndRowCount );
 });
 $.get( 'dynamic/total_word_count.php?u=<?php echo $uid; ?>', function(totalWordCount){
  $('#total_word_count').html( totalWordCount );
 });
 $.get( 'dynamic/scan_status.php?u=<?php echo $uid; ?>', function(scanStatus){
  $('#scan_status').html( scanStatus );
  if (scanStatus == 'finished') 
     {clearInterval(interval);}
 });
 $.get( 'dynamic/download_status.php?u=<?php echo $uid; ?>', function(downloadStatus){
  $('#download_status').html( downloadStatus );
 });
},3000); // 5000ms == 5 seconds
});
```

Comment: I think you mean "clearInterval" instead of stopInterval in the text of your answer.

Answer (score 0):

`setInterval` returns an id, that you can pass to `clearInterval` to stop the repeated calls.

setInterval is not jQuery by the way, but Ye Plain Olde Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `clearInterval` on the id you get when you call `setInterval`. Like this:

```
var intervalId = setInterval(
```

On the scan_status callback then you call

```
clearInterval(intervalId);
```